# English verb inflector

Tags: nlp

Does anybody know of an English verb inflector that I can use on a lexicon of verbs (in present-participle) that can give me other inflected forms of the verbs?

For example:

```
I give it     I get
=========     ======================================
run           ran, running, runs
sing          sang, singing, sings
play          played, playing, plays
```

Comment: Wordnet can also do this besides other libraries mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MorphAdorner](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/) can do this in Java.

Answer (score 5):

[Morphg](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html) is a stand-alone tool which provides this functionality. The inverse, i.e. finding the lemma of a verb, is provided by its sister, Morpha.

Answer (score 2):

CPAN's [Lingua::EN::Inflect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-Inflect/lib/Lingua/EN/Inflect.pm) will give you the plural forms, as well as helping you pick between 'a' and 'an' and pretty-printing numbers.

Comment: There's [`Lingua::EN::Conjugate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Conjugate) now, which is more directly relevant.