# English lemmatizer databases?

Tags: nlp, stemming, lemmatization, morphological-analysis

Do you know any big enough lemmatizer database that returns correct result for following sample words:

```
geese: goose
plantes: //not found
```

Wordnet's morphological analyzer is not sufficient, since it gives the following incorrect results:

```
geese: //not found
plantes: plant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MorphAdorner](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/lemmatizer/example/) seems to be better at this, but it still finds the incorrect result for "plantes"

```
plantes: plante
geese: goose
```

Maybe you'd like to use MorphAdorner to do the lemmatization, and then check its results against WordNet. You can use the WordNet API to perform lookups *without* first performing lemmatization by calling `findtheinfo_ds`. This allows you to use a lemmatizer like MorphAdorner first. (If you wanted to use the lemmaitzer, you'd need to call `morph` separately and call `findtheinfo_ds` on the lemmas that it returned.)

On the other hand, I only spent about 5 seconds looking at MorphAdorner for this purpose, and there may be a way to eliminate the incorrect "plantes" answer without having to use any other outside resource.

Comment: Thanks, after unchecking "Standardize spelling" it returns `plante` which can be checked against wordnet to find out it's not correct (I'm using wordnet files directly). But do you have any idea what "Early Modern English/Nineteenth Century Fiction" option is, are it's corpus recent enough to be used for modern english?

Comment: @Johns: That's what I was hinting at when I said I only spent about 5 seconds looking. Try looking through their documentation to see if it says anything.

Answer (score 1):

[Once upon a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178745/english-verb-inflector), someone suggested [Morpha](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html) to me, but I haven't used it, so I don't know if it does any better at this than WordNet does.

Comment: It doesn't have an online demo but reading descriptions it seems that it is not based on a database. But I will try it if I didn't run short of time.