# Is there an open-source self-learning stemmer?

Tags: nlp, stemming, morphological-analysis, lemmatization

I need to implement some sort of stemmer/lemmatizer. I have some words in different forms (a few thousands). It's not a morphological dictionary, just a small part of it. Is it a good idea to learn a stemmer automatically from the file a have? Is there any open-source implementations that can be used?

Comment: What do you need it for? (Depending on the application, different level/type of accuracy is required)

Comment: So, did you implement it?

Comment: Nope, didn't get enough time eventually

Answer (score 2):

Azerbaijani is an agglutinative language, similar to Turkish, which means words frequently have a chain of suffixes (e.g. one suffix for plural and one of accusative). Also it has vowel harmony, which means each suffix has several variants and you choose the correct one based on the vowels in the root.

What I would do:

- identify a list of suffixes. I would try both unsupervised methods (?maybe try [Linguistica](http://linguistica.uchicago.edu/index.html)?), and googling for a list of suffixes (these will often contain only a basic suffix which changes depending on vowel harmony). Iteratively you should arrive to some reasonable list. If in doubt if something is a suffix or not, I would throw it in.
- Use the list to strip suffixes from words.

The resulting stemmer will be noisy, but depending on what you need it for, it might not matter.

Comment: There is a service for Azerbaijani. It's not open source. The demo page of Azerbaijani stemmer is here: http://nlp.jsoft.ws/stemming

Answer (score 2):

Nuve is an NLP library for Turkic languages. Once the language rules and data are prepared, it can analyze and generate words for any Turkic language if not for any agglutinative language. You can fork it and prepare new orthography and morphology files for azeri.

https://github.com/hrzafer/nuve

Since I'm the author, I'd be glad to help you with the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Linguistica](http://linguistica.uchicago.edu/linguistica.html) which has been developed by John Goldsmith and his team (@UChicago) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about English? Then please see
[English lemmatizer databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308185/english-lemmatizer-databases). Considering the significant amount of exceptions, a machine-learning approach without a large dictionary does not seem promising.

Comment: No, it's not English, otherwise I would have used an existing lemmatizer. Unfortunately I didn't find anything except those few thousands of words. Also I don't speak this language at all. I'm not suggesting machine learning, I don't think it's applicable here. I'm thinking about building a stemmer by learning suffices from the list of words (there are different forms of the same words among them).